# Resize event for div resize

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, resize

I have a parent div and multiple child divs in flexbox mode with flex:1. On click, parent div gets smaller and child divs adjust accordingly in width. I want to get the width of child div on it's resize so that I can change it to a square by changing it's height.

Is it possible to do in angular or angular animations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using this directive [angular-resize-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event)

I found the issue with the library. On import for the app.module if you replace 
`import { AngularResizedEventModule } from 'angular-resize-event';` with 
 `import { AngularResizedEventModule } from 'angular-resize-event/dist';`

And on your component if you replace:

`import { ResizedEvent } from 'angular-resize-event';` with

`import { ResizedEvent } from 'angular-resize-event/dist/resized-event';`

and keep the rest of the instructions the same, the problem with using the directive is solved.

I will let the author know about the issue.

Comment: Tried using it. There is some issue with it's declaration. Can't figure out what. Can you help me with a stackblitz?